# How to extract a specific symbols from string if they follow after the number

Tags: python, string

I need to extract a single or multiple symbols `@` from a string. I only need those symbols that follow one after another and are not separated with any characters and white spaces.
The symbol or multiple symbols `@` should follow right after number. If not the symbols should be disregarded and not returned.

From a string `a` i would need to extract only three `@@@` symbols since the fourth symbol is separated with a white space character.

```
a='some text 1 a8 777@@@ @ more text here 123 456`
```

result would be:

```
@@@
```

From variable `b` the function would return `None` since not a single symbol `@` follows after a number or numbers.

```
b='some text @@@ @ more text here 123 456`
```

From `c` variable only a single symbol `@` is returned since it is the only one that follows after the numbers (and not separated from them):

```
c='some text @@@ 777@ more text here 123 456`
```

result: `@`

Comment: I'm sure this question will get answered because it's easy rep gain, but... what have you tried? Have you looked into regular expressions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use regex for this:

```
>>> import re
>>> r = re.compile(r'\d(@+)')
>>> a = 'some text 1 a8 777@@@ @ more text here 123 456'
>>> r.search(a).group(1)
'@@@'
>>> b = 'some text @@@ @ more text here 123 456'
>>> r.search(b) #None
>>> c = 'some text @@@ 777@ more text here 123 456'
>>> r.search(c).group(1)
'@'
```

Combine it with an `if` condition to check whether the regex matched anything in string or not:

```
>>> m = r.search(c)
>>> if m:
    print m.group(1)

@
```

Answer (score 1):

While there's probably a regular expression to do this, a loop is easier to understand if you don't know what regex-es are.

```py
i = 0
found = False
while i < len(string) and not found:
  if i != 0 and string[i] == '@':
    if string[i-1].isnumeric():
      found = True
    else:
      i+=1
  else:
    i+=1

if not found:
  return None
else:
  out = ''
  while string[i] == '@':
    out += '@'
    i+=1
  return out
```

Probably can be rewritten better, but that's the simplistic way to do it.

Footnote: A regex would be better though.

Answer (score 1):

```
import re

print re.findall('[0-9]@+', a)
```

This would print a list containing all the matches, in the above case it would print

```
['7@@@']
```

Now you can do slicing on the string, to get what you want.

Hope this helps !

Answer (score 0):

Does this work for you?

```
>>> import re
>>> re.search('\d(@+)', a).groups()[0]
'@@@'
>>> re.search('\d(@+)', b)
>>> re.search('\d(@+)', c).groups()[0]
'@'
```